# What is the proper method for creating dynamic hyperlinks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I know it's frowned upon to create links such as `<a href="javascript:my_func();">link text</a>` as this tricks the user into thinking it's a real link.

I have quite a few links that actually just run JS code in the browser instead of forcing page navigation, and as such I don't want to use the above and am looking for an alternative that works in all browsers **and** prevents *middle clicking* from opening a new tab/ window.

Would the following approach be satisfactory?

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="id_here">link text</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#id_here").bind('click',(function(params){
    return function(){
        // do stuff here with `params`
    };
})(params));
```

Comment: Oh, please also note that this is for a JavaScript modification for a forum host - so handlers for non JS users aren't useful at all!

Answer (score 3):

`javascript:` anything is bad.  There isn't much difference between the two `javascript:` uses above.  Using `"#"` for the `href` is about as bad; it adds to the history with JS off and the link is not useful.  What you should do (ideally) is have the link actually work, e.g.

```
<a href="/an/actual/path"> ...
```

Then, with JS, prevent default link behavior

```
$("#id_here").on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

If there is no actual path to go to, then the link should not even be exposed with JS off; you can either append it to the DOM later or just hide it with CSS (and show it with JS).

Comment: I should have said, this is for a JS only production, so there's no need to cater for those without JS.

Comment: In that case you don't even need an `href` or `e.preventDefault()`, (and you can use any element, but `<a>` probably makes the most sense semantically).

Comment: @KeirSimmons: Then cater for those using middle click! Why can't I open your link in a new tab if I want to?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` suppresses the natural action of the hyperlink, hence href="#" will not add to the history object. Some browsers need a non-null href in order to properly render anchors as clickable - "#" is the best option. Personally, I don't cater for browsers with js off.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: "it adds to the history _with JS off_"

Comment: @Eric, the links open modal boxes - as I said its a completely JS oriented production, everything is accessible through one page and one page only.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot NO, `#` will add to the history if JS is off.  Non-null href has nothing to do with "rendering anchors as clickable," that is very misleading!  I suppose you mean most browsers have default css for clickable links (such as `a:-webkit-any-link`) but you can very easily apply your own styles to make it look like a clickable link.

Comment: @KeirSimmons: Would it be valid in this case to open a modal box, but in a duplicate of the current page in a new tab?

Comment: @KeirSimmons may be better to display nothing if JS is off then, at least to prevent accidents.  Or maybe a "Turn JS On" message or something.

Comment: The entire code is a modification for an existing forum software (JS modification). So if JS is turned off, the links won't even be added (it's basically just a visual enhancer for those with JS).

Comment: @KeirSimmons all of my advice still stands.

Comment: "/an/actual/path" - so why not "#", which is (or at least expands to) an actual path? "/an/actual/path" makes a nonsense of the rest of the answer.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I don't know what the intended path is .. that was just a placeholder for what it would be.  I didn't mean for him to literally type `/an/actual/path`!

Comment: It's simple, (a) attach javascript handlers in javascript not HTML, (b) href="#" unless there's a reason for some other URL, (c) if natural hyperlink action is to be suppressed, then `e.preventDefault();` (or return false in non-jQuery code) - return anything other than `false` to allow allow the hyperlink action, (d) unless there's a very compelling reason, don't cater for browsers with js turned off. Anything else is going to confuse noobs. And yes, of course I realise that `/an/actual/path` is a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you used another node other than `<a>`, such as a `<div>`:

```
<div id="jsLink" style="cursor:pointer">Click Me</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$("#jsLink").click(function(params){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: **-1** - not a good idea - won't be tab-able to, for instance

Comment: And do not forget to style your div to make it look like a link. Oh. Also it is a div - block element

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="id_here">link text</a>
```

# is here to make a link look like link
JavaScript:

```
$("#id_here").bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

e.preventDefault() does not allow browser to execute default action (like navigate to another page)

Comment: I might show the user a slightly more meaningful url such as `#!/edit-post`

Comment: No matter what will be in href, except that it should not be empty. Otherwise it will be displayed like a span

Answer (score 0):

I did some playing around, and you can get some [good results](http://jsfiddle.net/jgEyY/show) with `hashchange`:

```
var commands = {
    foo: function() { alert("Foo!"); },
    bar: function() { alert("Foo bar!"); },
    baz: function() { alert("Foo bar baz!"); }
};

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace(/^#/,'');
    if(commands[hash]) {
        commands[hash]();
        return false;
    }
}).trigger('hashchange');​
```

With the simple HTML of:

```
<a href="#foo">Foo</a>
<a href="#bar">Bar</a>
<a href="#baz">Baz</a>​
```

This even works if you right click -> open in new tab or middle click!

---

Note that `hashchange` is not supported by all browsers.